# regex match number after (

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am trying to use regex to match a a variable length of digits after the open bracket '(' character.

I have tried

```
\(\d+
```

But that regex includes the bracket in the match. How do I exclude it?

I am using sublime text regex engine to do the match.

Comment: Is it JavaScript?

Comment: sublime text build system regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\()\d+
```

**There is one limitation here**: you can only have a pattern of *known width* in the lookbehind. You may use `(?<=\(|\s{5})\d+`, but you cannot use `(?<=\d:\s*)\d+`.

[image]

You may use `\K` "match reset" operator to work around the length limit in the lookbehind since `\K` just "truncates" the match at the place where it is used, all text matched by the pattern to the left of it is omitted:

```
\(\K\d+
```

[[image]]

Note that `\K` is not actually a lookbehind equivalent since the text before it is *consumed* while lookbehinds do not consume text.

Comment: Working with RegEx for years and this is the first time I see that `\K` operator. Thanks!

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak: It is a useful operator coming from Perl available in PCRE, Boost and Onigmo regex libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use capturing groups:

```
/\((\d+)/
```

The non-escaped brackets are a regex matching group which you can extract from each match. If you have a search'n'replace system, the `$1` is often used to access the groups.