# Positive look behind regex usage

Tags: regex

I am using positive lookbehind to assert a string of characters in a regex and it is failing.

I want to match the first line number in these following examples...

> 1>c:\src\head\foo.cpp(29)
>
> 2>c:\head\src\bar.cs(400):

I first tried matching any string of digits after opening bracket '(' as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119058/regex-match-number-after/42119115#42119115). In this case the positive look behind worked successfully.

```
(?<=\()\d+
```

Then I crafted a regex to more accurately match everything before the line number...

```
\d+>c:\\.*\..*\(
```

This regex worked correctly.

Then I assumed that I could put the second regex into the positive look behind, to get a more rigorous match against the line number...

```
(?<=\d+>C:\\.*\..*\()\d+
```

And this regex fails to match anything. What have I missed here?

Comment: Lookbehind are fixed length only (no `+`,`*` nor `?`). Put your regex in http://regex101.com and it will explain it to you :)

Comment: The alternative is to use capture groups: without look-behind just match the whole string, but put parentheses around `\d+` so that it becomes a capture group. In most languages you can get the part captured by that group.

Comment: Does positive look behind support alternation | operator inside of it?

Comment: @ScottF Yes, you can use alternation as long as alternate values are of the same size.

Comment: **Use `\K`**: `\d+>C:\\.*\..*\(\K\d+`, it works as expected with an unknown width "prefexes".